# Стоит ли добавлять в redux store свойства css стилей компонентов?

Tags: css, reactjs, css3, css-animation, redux

Верстаю учебный проект и по какой-то причине перестали работать некоторые специфические классы styled-tailwind-css. В частности, перестали работать группы (group в родительском и group-hover в дочернем), но это навело на мысли о том насколько правильно в принципе доверять такую комплексную отрисовку css? Возможно было бы правильно все эти хуверы также поместить в редакс стейты и менять визуальные свойства компонентов также с помощью javascript. Все таки современные стили берут на себя гораздо больше функций, чем раньше и зачастую не ограничиваются одним только внешним видом да и внешний вид также имеет смысл контролировать явно, не полагаясь во всем только на способности браузеров понимать те или иные сss функции. С другой стороны в интернете не так уж много примеров где те же хуверы учитывались бы редюсерами. В общем, я в замешательстве. Идеологически кажется правильным все учитывать в сторе, но опасаюсь что в большом проекте это может быть огромным оверкодом.

Comment: Все что касается визуального представления компонентов - лучше держать в стилях. Редакс это стейт бизнес-логики, а не внешнего вида элементов - состояние и UI следует разделять на всех уровнях взаимодействия (JSX в этом плане плох, но впадать в крайности из-за этого и безумно смешивать ответственности - так себе вариант). Связь между состоянием и внешним видом (стилями), в вебприложениях обычно обеспечивается классами элементов. Локальные для элемента псевдоклассы - забота исключительно стилей (вмешиваемся кодом только если возможностей CSS недостаточно).

Comment: Классы в редаксе тоже держать не стоит, т.к. они принадлежат локальной области ответственности (уровню компонентов), а не общему стейту приложения. Разве что редакс используется "кластерно", множеством экземпляров... а это уже сомнительная экзотика :) В качестве альтернативы, можно выделить редакс-модуль под состояние UI, чтобы не смешивать его с состоянием приложения и данных (но все же, трудно советовать держать классы в стейте, это на границе плохих практик).

Comment: @yar85 Я часто оборачиваю все контейнерные компоненты в декораторы и они, увы, работают только с классовыми объектами. Я решил что, в случае, если css стиль оказывает влияние не только на сам компонент, но и на зависимые от него компоненты его все таки стоит внести в стор. Не сам компонент, конечно, а определенные состояния компонента. В частности, вынес свойство hover.

Comment: В стор конечно же имеет смысл переносить те переменные которые влияют на текущее состояние компонентов в приложении (а следовательно, на набор css-классов их элементов). Но если стили влияют на состояние - это неок, "обратное связывание" лучше устранять: например, можно добавить пропсы из которых локально вычисляется и лок.стейт, и стили. Конечно, могут быть нюансы из-за общего несовершенства подходов принятых в React/JSX, но в общем и целом лучше передавать всю ответственность за внешний вид компонента самому компоненту, инкапсулировать эту логику (упростит дальнейшую работу с кодовой базой).